# How do I set the blog name?

Tags: title

I am new to WordPress and don't know how to set the "blog name".
I need to change a current value that has been coded (or set) somewhere for the home page only.
It is appearing in the title, and I don't know how to update it.
Thanks.

Comment: No one can really help unless you post some code or a site URL.

Answer (score 2):

Go to admin dashboard > Settings > General

You are getting General Settings...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the "Site Name" in the settings?

In the admin area, go to Settings >> General >> Site Title to enter the title.